# Normal closure of a radical extension is radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm struggling to understand the proof that the normal closure of a radical extension of fields is also a radical extension, which is crucial since it allows us to work with radical *and* normal extensions (and thus, in characteristic 0, with radical Galois extensions).

The proof I'm reading is lemma 4.17 in Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra, pp. 211-212, which I attach at the end of this message.

The definition Rotman uses is the following: an extension $F\subset F(u)$ is *pure* if there exists $m \geq 1$ such that $u^m\in F$. An extension $F\subset K$ is *radical* if there exists a tower (which I like to call *radical tower*) $$F=K_0\subset K_1\subset \dots \subset K_t=K$$ such that $K_i\subset K_{i+1}$ is pure for all $i$.

What I'm struggling to prove is: if $F\subset K$ is a radical extension, and $N$ is the normal closure of the extension, then $F\subset N$ is a radical extension.

Since I find Rotman's proof confusing (and not convincing), I have rewritten the proof. It might seem longer in appearance, but the first part of the proof (the one that troubles me) was unsatisfying. Let $m_{\alpha,F}$ denote the minimal polynomial for an element $\alpha$ over $F$.

What I ask is:

> 1) Is my rewriting of the proof correct?
>
> 2) Is this what's behind the argument of Rotman, or is there another, more simple way of reading it?

Rotman's proof seems shorter, but I don't understand when he says "it follows that $E=k(\sigma(u_1),\dots,\sigma(u_t):\sigma \in G)$": what are those $u_i$?

Here's my rewriting:

Let $F\subset K$ be a radical extension. There exist $u_1,\dots,u_t$ such that $$F\subset F(u_1)\subset F(u_1,u_2)\subset \dots \subset F(u_1,\dots,u_t) = K$$ is a radical tower. Let $E$ be the normal closure of $F\subset K$. I claim that$$E=F\left(\\{\sigma(u_i): \sigma \in \text{Gal}^E_F, i=1,\dots,t\\}\right)$$

Indeed, $$E=\text{Split}_F\left(m_{u_1,F} \dots m_{u_t,F}\right)=F(\{\text{roots of }m_{u_1,F} \dots m_{u_t,F}\})$$

Since the Galois group of a polynomial acts transitively on its roots, $\{\text{roots of }m_{u_i,F}\}=\{\sigma(u_i):\sigma \in \text{Gal}_F(m_{u_i,F})\}$. Let us see that is also equals $\{\sigma(u_i):\sigma \in \text{Gal}^E_F\}$.

$(\subset)$: We can extend every $\sigma\in \text{Gal}_F(m_{u_i,F})$ to $\tilde{\sigma}\in \text{Gal}_F^E$ by the theorem of extension of a polynomial to its splitting field, by taking the polynomial $m_{u_1,F} \dots m_{u_t,F}\in F[X]$.

$(\supset)$: If $\sigma\in \text{Gal}^E_F$, then $\sigma$ restricts to an $F$-isomorphism $F(u_i)\to F(\sigma(u_i))$, then (corollary 1.9 p.236 of Hungerford)  $u_i$ and $\sigma(u_i)$ must be roots of the same irreducible polynomial in $F[X]$. This proves that $\sigma(u_i)$ is a root of $m_{u_i,F}$.

Let $B_i=F\left(\{\sigma(u_j):1\leq j\leq i,\sigma \in\text{Gal}^E_F\}\right)$. What we just proved is that $E=B_t$. To see that $F\subset E= B_t$ es radical, we use induction on $t$, and this part of Rotman's proof is satisfying to me.

Below is Rotman's proof.

[image]

Comment: I think he should have said that $u_1, \ldots, u_t$ are elements of $B$ such that for each $i = 1, \ldots, t - 1$ some power of $u_{i + 1}$ is contained in $F(u_1, \ldots, u_i)$. Your proof looks good. I think you just needed to write out the details for yourself, which is good!

Comment: @Dylan: What puzzles me is that if all the details I wrote out are necessary, then I think the author should have been a bit more verbose on the proof...

Comment: I must say I'm a bit surprised by the lack of answers to this question. It shouldn't take too long to answer for somebody comfortable with Galois theory.

Comment: What would you like to see in such an answer? It looks like both you and Rotman have correct proofs, and for me it's hard to imagine a shorter argument!

Comment: The one problem I have with what Rotman is saying here (and I could be missing something) is that you might have repeated $p_i$ in part (i), e.g. for $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i\sqrt[4]{2})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that both you and Rotman have the same argument in mind. Here's another way of looking at this.

Let $B$ be a finite extension of $k$, and let $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_s$ be the distinct embeddings over $k$ of $B$ into an algebraic closure $B^a$ of $B$. I claim that a normal closure of $B/k$ is the compositum $E = (\sigma_1B) \cdots (\sigma_sB)$. If $B$ is given as $k(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ then $\sigma_iB = k(\alpha_1^{\sigma_i}, \ldots, a_n^{\sigma_i})$, and we have rules like $k(\alpha)k(\beta) = k(\alpha, \beta)$. Each of the $\sigma_i$ will extend to an element of $\operatorname{Gal}(E/k)$, and your result follows.

Of course, you need to prove that $E$ really is normal over $k$, and minimal among such extensions containing $B$. But that's not too hard, and conceptually I think this is nice.