# Let $K$ be a subfield of $\mathbb {C}$ and let $L$ be the splitting field of $t^n-1$ over $K$. When is the Galois group of $L:K$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

The author proves that whenever $n$ is prime, the Galois group of $L:K$ is indeed abelian, yet it seems to me that the argument could be extended to all natural numbers $n$.

---

The author's proof:

[image]

---

The argument extended for all natural numbers $n$:

The zeroes of $t^n -1$ are the $n$th roots of unity, namely $e^{k2 \pi i/n}$ for $k = 0, 1, ..., n-1$. These roots are all different and form a group $G$ under multiplication where $e^{2 \pi i/n}=\epsilon$ generates $G$, thus $G$ is cyclic and abelian. Furthermore $L=K(\epsilon)$. The argument follows as before.

---

My concern is that the arguments are practically equal, so I don't understand why the author would only prove the theorem for the case where $n$ is prime, such idea makes me feel like I'm missing something.

Can the theorem actually be extended for all natural numbers or is my proof flawed?

---

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts.

Comment: Yes, a cyclotomic extension is always abelian, but not always cyclic (this might be why the author takes $p$ to be prime – otherwise the "we can say more" sentence is wrong). Your proof is flawed: you only have an injective morphism $Gal(L/K) \to (\Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z)^{\times}$.

Comment: @Watson. So, just to confirm, the theorem would hold for all natural numbers $n$, right?

Comment: Yes, for every $n \geq 1$ and every perfect field $K$, the splitting field of $T^n-1 \in K[T]$ has abelian Galois group over $K$.

Comment: @Watson. One more thing. It seems it is not possible to private message someone through this website, so I will write the following as a comment and I apologize if it is unrelated to the question posted. I asked [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970531/if-lk-is-a-radical-extension-in-mathbb-c-then-the-normal-closure-mk) a couple of days ago, and was wondering if you could check it out since the content is related to this post.